# much slower run time pc mac gfortran

Tags: macos, performance, windows-7, gfortran

I am compiling fortran code on both my macbook pro (10.9.5, 2.3GHz, 8 GB RAM) and on my Dell Latitude E6400 (Windows 7, @.26GHz, 4GB RAM). The code runs in about 12.2 minutes on the mac and 32.6 minutes on the pc. I am using gfortran (4.9.0 on the mac, 4.10.0 on the pc). My make file is:

{

```
# Makefile for NRMMII

F95 = gfortran
#FINCLUD=
#OBJPATH=./objG95/

# .F90 invokes the fpp preprocessor whereas .f90 does not
# the preprocessor expands source code "macros" and symbolic definitions prior to compilation
# it makes no difference with nrmm30

# compiler flags
#FLAGSC = -ffree-form -fall-intrinsics -fcheck=all -m64 -c
FLAGSC = -std=f95 -v -ffree-form -O0 -fall-intrinsics -fcheck=all -march=native -flto \
         -funroll-loops -fno-protect-parens  -fstack-arrays -c

# link flags
FLAGSL = -g 
#-static   Only for windows machines


OBJS =  module_nrmmdefs.f90 module_nrmmcntc.f90 module_nrmmdevc.f90 \
    module_nrmmdrvc.f90 module_nrmmploc.f90 module_nrmmprdc.f90 \
    module_nrmmscnc.f90 module_nrmmstsc.f90 module_nrmmsumc.f90 \
    module_nrmmterc.f90 module_nrmmtppc.f90 module_nrmmvehc.f90 \
    module_nrmmvers.f90 module_nrmmvppc.f90 module_nrmm_global.f90 \
    module_nrmmpbuffs.f90 module_nrmmxmlc.f90 \
    main.f90 areal.f90 auxout.f90 crlsno.f90 diag.f90 histogram.f90\
    input.f90 miscg95.f90 plow.f90 road.f90 summary.f90 terrain.f90\
    vpp.f90 spclxml2.f90 nrmmxml.f90

# special files in nrmmii_misc
#   module_spclapfc.f90 spclapf.f90 module_spclresc.f90 spclres.f90 \
#   spcljody.f90 spclnode.f90 spclnode1.f90 spclnull.f90 spcltrfs.f90\
#   module_nrmmxmlc.f90 nrmmxml.f90 spclxml2.f90 spcltrav.f90 


#       This defines the compile rules

.SUFFIXES:      .o .f90


.f90.o:
    $(F95) $(FLAGSC) $*.f90

nrmm30:
    $(F95) $(FLAGSL) -o $@ $(OBJS)
```

}

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the pc version is running so much slower?

Comment: `-O0`, `-g`? If you want to benchmark things, at least let the compiler optimize... Also how much ram does your program use/need?

Comment: I have tried optimization levels -O0 through -Ofast and saw almost no difference in speed. Removing the -g link option also doesn't affect run time. I don't know how much ram my program uses/needs.

Comment: How much output does the code produce - I/O systems vary greatly.